# Call another method from a DialogClick Event Handler method

Tags: android, xamarin, events, dialog, click

I have an alert dialog that contains an array of the names of the websites a user could want to visit as builder items. Now the first name is Facebook and I want a WebView declared in my class load the facebook url when this item is clicked on via the DialogClick Event handler but all the variables i declared in my class including my webview are invisible to this DialogClick Event Handler, figured I should try a function pointer or a delegate but am stuck please help...
C# code for the Alert dialog and the method to listen on item tapped below

```
  class Internet : AppCompatActivity,Android.Webkit.IDownloadListener, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener
    {
        WebView webview;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Browser);
//webview definition
    webview=this.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview1); 
   //Button that shows the dialog on click
    Button f=this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        f.Click +=show;
         }
  //Method to build and show alert dialog
private void show(object sender, EventArgs e){
 string[] items = new string[5] { "Facebook", "Google", "Instagram", "Twitter","Reddit" };

Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder =new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.SetTitle("Menu Items");
                    builder.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.avatar);
//This function pointer in here called handler is the one that handles the dialog click event 
                    builder.SetItems(items, handler);
                    });
                    dialog.Show();
}
//Handler method to take care of an item clicked on the dialog
 EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs> handler = (s, o) => {
            // save off selected event
            switch (o.Which)
            {
                case 0:
                    
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on facebook", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    //Tried to make variable webview load facebook url but the variable is invisible to this scope
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on Google", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on Reddit", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
            }
              

        };
}
```

I need code that will make all the webview variable i declared in my class visible in this method or an effective function pointer that will make another method to which the webview is visible load the url for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the handler in another way:

```
class Internet : AppCompatActivity
{
    public WebView webview;
   
    EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs> handler { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        handler += test;
    }

    public void test(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Which)
        {
            case 0:

                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on facebook", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                //Tried to make variable webview load facebook url but the variable is invisible to this scope
                webview.LoadUrl("123");

                break;

            case 1:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on Google", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "You tapped on Reddit", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant believe am saying this but your method worked, your a great programmer Mr, you get an accepted answer and upvote on your answer